# RAZORSDK1007: Errors when add "Razor Class Library" reference to .NET6 Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a new" blazor webassembly" and a "Razor Class Library" for components. But I get an the following error. I don't know what is meant by the warning and error since I can't understand the file itself (Server or Client even Shared)

warning: Warning RAZORSDK1007 Reference assembly C:\Users\ArnoS Es\source\repos\Issuetracker\Bugtracker\Client\bin\Debug\net6.0\Bugracker.Client.dll could not be found. This is typically caused by build errors in referenced projects.

It's not very clear to me where the warning is coming from in the code since I don't understand where he gets the reference to talk to the Client-side in Blazor

The error: Metadata file 'C\Users\ArnoS\Source\Repos\Issuetracker\Bugtracker\Client\bin\Debug\net6.0\Bugtracker.Client.dll' could not be found

[image]

Comment: I don't get any errors when a built the Bugtracker Client project. That's what I find so strange. Only when I build the Server project do I get errors that he can't find the file

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: The project just runs on my local machine

Comment: If you clean the project,and rebuild it,can it be solved?

Comment: I tried to clean every project and rebuild it but it still gives me the same error. Every time I rebuild the server he gives me this error. I decided to begin from scratch and do my architecture build up a bit different. I was working with different layers according to the clean architecture pattern